# From a component-type Class, how do you get the array-of Class in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

In effect, I want the "opposite" of:

```
java.lang.Class.getComponentType()
```

I have a Class (but I don't know what X is; this is totally generic), and I want to get the Class.

Comment: @LukeWoodward Yes, this is the same thing I want to do. So it is a duplicate.  :(

Answer (score 1):

You can create array `Class` from its component `Class` with [java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int%29)

Comment: Thanks, but that was not what I asked for.

Comment: @SebastienDiot can you clarify your question? Maybe add an example?

Answer (score 1):

Took me a few tries to get it right:

```
Class<?> s = Foo.class;
Class<?> as = Class.forName( "[L" + s.getCanonicalName() + ";" );
```

Doesn't handle primitives though.

Edit: turns out this doesn't handle the case where `s` already represents an array type.